# Get element from object stored in a list

Tags: java, android

I have  a list of only 1 object. I need to retrieve it from list and then use this object. This is my example -

```
public CurrentPosition getCurrentNo(){
    List<CurrentPositionDB>currentPositionDBs = readAllPosition();//list has only 1 object
    CurrentPositionDB result = null;
    CurrentPosition currentPosition = new CurrentPosition();
    if(currentPositionDBs!=null && !currentPositionDBs.isEmpty()) {
       //retrieve object from currentPositionDBs list and use it to assign for currentPosition object
    }
        return currentPosition;
}
```

Comment: You should check some methods in the `List` interface. Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

Comment: you can simply use `list.get(0)` right?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<currentPositionsDBs.size();i++){ //your object currentPositionsDBs.get(i);}

Answer (score 0):

Use this code     `currentPositionDBs.get(0)`

Answer (score 0):

As @TheLostMind mind said in his/her comment, you should look into the documentation on util.List

What you are looking for though would be along these lines:

```
currentPosition = currentPositionDBs.get(0);
```